# Cypress "Downloads" on Ubuntu Server with Chromium

Tags: ubuntu, jenkins, cypress, chromium, ubuntu-server

I run some test with cypress and chromium on my Ubuntu desktop 20.04, every thing is fine.
But if I run the test on a Ubuntu server 20.04 they fail with a message that the file is not inside the downloadsFolder i try to read.

I set in cypress.json

```
"downloadsFolder": "xmlfiles",
```

When I do the download with cypress there is not error. But after going a step further to read in the XML files cypress cannot find the file in the `xmlfiles` folder.
I assume that `xmlfiles` is detected as part of the root, where `cypress.json` is.
like

- e2e
- - cypress.json
- - xmlfiles

As far as I can see, Ubuntu server do not have a common downloads folder in the home path.
like `/home/devops/Downloads`. Is there a trick or a special setting I have to do with cypress?

To not forget, I run this with Jenkins.

Comment: Where is xmlfiles ? Is it in root folder of project ?

Comment: @mosaad yes it is a subfolder from the projectfolder where cypress.json is stored.